The picture is in a tilted oval. Jetpack compose
I want to make a picture that would be cropped with a tilted oval. In addition, there should also be a white border. How can I achieve this?


The simplest solution is to use a RoundedCornerShape with corner radius percentages. Here's an example:
@Preview
@Composable
private fun TiltedOvalImage() {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xFF7E7E7E)),
    ) {
        val shape = remember {
            RoundedCornerShape(
                topStartPercent = 100,
                bottomEndPercent = 100,
                topEndPercent = 45,
                bottomStartPercent = 45,
            )
        }
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.sample),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(250.dp)
                .clip(shape)
                .border(5.dp, Color.Companion.White, shape)
        )
    }
}

Here's the result:

Photo by Irina Iriser on Unsplash
